# What is the average consumption of a GPS app (data-wise)?

Tags: gps, smartphone, traffic

I'm currently working on a school project to design a network, and we're asked to assess traffic on the network. In our solution (dealing with taxi drivers), each driver will have a smartphone that can be used to track its position to assign him the best ride possible (through Google Maps, for instance).

What would be the size of data sent and received by a single app during one day? (I need a rough estimate, no real need for a precise answer to the closest bit)

Thanks

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not a programming question.

Comment: do you mean I should move it to another StackExchange site or modify the tags?

Comment: You first need to specify what is the recording intervall: once a second? or one location in 5 minutes. And how fast the location must transmitted. You said "received"; Doi you mean only the app, or do you mean that you must transfer this position to  a server.

Comment: But be warned: don't try to implement a navigation solution, even the simplest working approach needs some years of effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gps Positions compactly stored, but not compressed needs this number of bytes:

time    : 8   (4 bytes is possible too)
latitude: 4  (if used as integer or float) or 8 
longitude 4 or 8
speed: 2-4 (short: 2: integer 4)
course (2-4)

So binary stored in main memory, one location including the most important attributes, will need 20 - 24 bytes. 
If you store them in main memory as single location object, additonal 16 bytes per object are needed in a simple (java) solution. 
The maximum recording frequence is usually once per second (1/s): Per hour this need: 3600s * 40 byte = 144k. So a smartphone easily stores that even in main memory.

Not sure if you want to transmit the data:

When transimitting this to a server data usually will raise, depending of the transmit protocoll used.

But it mainly depends how you transmit the data and how often.
If you transimit every 5 minutes a position, you dont't have to care, even
when you use a simple solution that transmits 100 times more bytes than neccessary.

For your school project, try to transmit not more than every 5 or better 10 minutes.
Encryption adds an huge overhead.

To save bytes:
- Collect as long as feasible, then transmit at once. 
- Favor binary protocolls to text based. (BSON better than JSON), (This might be out of scope for your school project)